# Force autocomplete to populate on javascript click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, click, bookmarklet

I am working on Bookmarklet and having an issue with click function in Javascript.
On google home page, If I manually click search bar then it populates my recent searches but when I go to Dev console and use click() on the search box element then it doesn't populate my recent searches.

[Manual Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEI2l.png)

[Console Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJgrX.png)

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: there is a single line of code and i have included that in the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should emulate mouse events. Perhaps something like this:

```
javascript:(function() {
    fireMouseEvent(document.querySelector("#lst-ib"));

    function fireMouseEvent(eltTarget) {
        var screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY;
        var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window, 1, screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        eltTarget.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
})();
```

Comment: I rather not use coordinates to map the element.